# What is the most efficient implementation of arrays with functional updates?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, functional-programming, ocaml, immutability

I need an array-like data structure with the fastest possible functional update. I've seen a few different implementation of flexible arrays that provide me with this property (Braun, Random Access Lists) but I'm wondering if there is an implementation that is specifically optimized for the case when we are not interested in append or prepend - just updates.

Comment: Surely a map of some kind?

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra an immutable map? wouldn't it be even costlier than the array?

Comment: Dominic, maps, Braun, and RAL are all tree based. I'm looking to see if there is maybe some clever combination with an imperative array (that is not mutated) that can beat a pure tree based data structure.

Comment: I'd imagine a HAMT (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie) is probably a good bet for you. It's basically like Haskell's `IntMap` but usually presented with a more Array-like interface (see for example Scala's Vector class or its counterpart in Clojure)

Comment: copumpkin: a topical comment as a HAMT implementation for OCaml was released [just a few days ago](http://gallium.inria.fr/blog/implementing-hamt-for-ocaml/). See my answer for a simpler implementation of persistent arrays, close to the "version arrays" mentioned by Michael Day.

Comment: check out [hashed array tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashed_array_tree) (without re-sizing) - just a list (not linked, an array of pointers to) of chunks. On access, make a new copy of a chunk, and a new top. Or instead of an addressing array, maintain a tree.

Comment: Dietz showed how to get O(log (log m)) per operation, where m is the number of updates. That's fully persistent, not functional. It could probably be written in Haskell using horrible mutation under the hood but exposing a pure interface. Can't say if it would be fast in practice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jean-Cristophe Filliâtre has [a very nice implementation](http://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/puf/) of persistent arrays, that is described in [the paper](http://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/ftp/publis/puf-wml07.ps) linked at the same page (which is about persistent union-find, of which persistent arrays are a core component). The code is directly available [there](http://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/ftp/ocaml/ds/parray.ml.html).

The idea is that "the last version" of the array is represented as an usual array, with `O(1)` access *and* update operations, and previous versions are represented as this last version, plus a list of the differences. If you try to access a previous version of the structure, the array is "rerooted" to apply the list of differences and present you again the efficient representation.

This will of course not be O(1) under all workflows (if you constantly access and modify unrelated versions of the structure, you will pay rerooting costs frequently), but for the common workflow of mainly working with one version, and occasionally backtracking to an older version that becomes the "last version" again and gets the updates, this is very efficient. A very nice use of mutability hidden under a observationally pure interface.

Answer (score 4):

I have a very good experience with [repa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa) ([nice demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UGN0GxGEDsY)). Very good performance, automatic parallelism, multidimensional, polymorphic. Recommended to try.

Answer (score 2):

Which language are you using? In Haskell you can use [mutable arrays](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/array/Data-Array-ST.html) with the state monad, and in Mercury you can use mutable arrays by threading the IO state. Ocaml also has an array module, which unfortunately does not maintain referential transparency, if that is what you are after.

Comment: I'm using OCaml. I tagged the question as Haskell as to tap the community's knowledge of these things. Btw, I'm not sure how STArray will solve my problem of using updating an array while keeping the old copy available efficiently.

Comment: OCaml arrays are mutable, they don't have persistence. Constant-time access with updates and persistence seems pretty difficult if not impossible. So, a map is probably what you want (as suggested above).

Comment: There are many different map based implementations, I'm looking for the best for my use case. For example a balanced BST would be terrible for this application. Although the asymptotic performance is the same.

Comment: Mercury has version arrays, which offer O(1) access to the latest version of the array and O(n) access to older versions, where n is the number of updates that have been made since the old version.

Answer (score 1):

I also needed functional arrays and felt on this SO question some days ago. I was not satisfied with the solution proposed by Gasche as creating a new array is a costly operation and I need to access older versions of array quite frequently (I plan to use this for an AI alpha/beta implementation playing on an array).

(When I say costly, I guess it is O(n*h) where h is the history size because in the worst case only one cell was updated repeatedly and it is needed to go through the whole update list for each cell. I also expect most of the cells not being updated when I need to reroute the array).

This is why I propose another approach, maybe I can get some feedback here. My idea is to store the array like in a B-Tree, except that as it is not mutable, I can access and update any value by index quite easily.

I wrote a small introduction on the project's repository : https://github.com/shepard8/ocaml-ptarray. The order is chosen so as to even depth and order of the tree, so I can get nice complexities depending only on the order for get/set operations, namely O(k^2).

With k = 10 I can store up to 10^10 values. Actually my arrays should not contain more than 200 values but this is to show how robust my solution is intended to be.

Any advice welcome!