# About the complexity of Map.remove in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

It seems `Map.remove` will return a new map structure, leaving the original map the same.

How can the complexity still be O(lg n)?

Answer (score 6):

Most of the previous map is shared by the new map. Only a small part is different. You can read all about why immutable data structures perform surpisingly well in Chris Okasaki's thesis [Purely Functional Data Structures](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf).

Comment: The code looks like you would expect, except it always creates new tree nodes rather than modifying existing ones. Any unmodified parts of the tree appear in both the old and new trees. The difficulty is in the analysis, not in the coding. The removal case is one of the more complex ones. You can see the code for a map in the [OCaml Batteries Include Map implementation](https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included/blob/master/src/batIMap.ml). Wikipedia has a pretty good page on [persistent data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure).

Comment: @JeffreyScofield, did you intentionally link to `BatIMap.ml`, which has a fairly different implementation from the more usual `BatMap.ml`?

Comment: Whoops, I was trying to link to BatMap. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 6):

If that can give you an intuition, here is an implementation of stacks
with a `O(1)` Stack.pop, that returns a new structure, keeping
the previous one unchanged (see how I pop `test` twice).

```
type 'a stack = Stack of 'a list
let empty = Stack []
let push x (Stack xs) = Stack (x :: xs)
let pop = function
  | Stack [] -> raise Not_found
  | Stack (x::xs) -> x, Stack xs


(* testing the structure in the toplevel *)

# let test = push 1 (push 2 (push 3 empty));;
val test : int stack = Stack [1; 2; 3]
# let (n, test2) = pop test;;
val n : int = 1
val test2 : int stack = Stack [2; 3]
# pop test2;;
- : int * int stack = (2, Stack [3])
# (* but the starting stack 'test' is still available *)
  pop test;;
- : int * int stack = (1, Stack [2; 3])
```

#### Why are some structures functional and some other imperative?

This boils down to algorithmic issues. There are so-called "Purely Functional Data Structure" that have the property that you can implement the operation you want in such a way that most of the data can be shared between different copies of the structure -- note that this relies crucially on aliasing, which will be observable if the elements of those structure are mutable.

In the `list` example, taking the tail of a list gives you a different list that is also part of the previous one, so there is no copy of data involved. For `Map.remove` (or other map-modifying operations), you will typically modify the path from the root of a balanced tree to the node you're interested in, so this path (of logarithmic height) will be different in the two structures, but the rest of the tree, that is the left and right subtrees along that path, will not be modified and can be shared between both structures, leading to only logarithmic memory allocation.

Jeffrey pointed to Okasaki's excellent work on such data structures (it is edited as a book that I definitely recommend, but only if you're really interested in this rather advanced subject), where a lot of data structures based on these ideas are implemented.

But on the contrary, some other structures are hard to make persistent in this way. Typically, an array is a very flat structure that contains a large number of element. So if you want to return a modified version of the array, you basically have to either mutate the existing array in place (losing the previous version, so that's not persistent) or copy the whole array to a new version (linear time and memory cost). The previous example worked because there are some indirections with independent substructures (subtrees of the balanced trees, tail of a list) that can be used on their own without copy; but an array is only flat structure with no such independent substructure. But that can be an interesting performance trade-off: the lack of indirection is precisely why array access is constant-time (forgetting about caches here), while lookup in a balanced tree is more expensive (`O(log n)` is small but sensibly more than array's `O(1)` in actual practice).

The reason why hashtables are mutable is that they are implemented on top of arrays. A hashtable is an array of "buckets" (implemented as lists or, if you're wise, a tree datastructure), where each bucket contain all the elements that hash to the same key in the array. Updating the hashtable means updating the bucket (which can be done in a persitent way), but then you need to update the array, and this is non-persistent for the same reason as above.

Note that not all is lost: you can come up with persistent versions of such data-structure. You can always do that by paying a `O(log n)` cost (by representing your mutable memory as a persistent balanced tree from integers to stuff), but in most cases you can also be clever and come with persistent data structures that are faster than that, hopefully only *a bit* slower than the counterpart that is not concerned with persistency. There are various tradeoffs involved, but if you application *needs* persistence (for example you're representing the state of a system for which you need to snapshot the state frequently, and sometimes backtrack to earlier versions) you'll glad to have those alternatives around.

In this vein, see [this discussion of persistent arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14703968/298143), and [this blog post](http://gallium.inria.fr/blog/implementing-hamt-for-ocaml/) for an OCaml implementation of HAMT, a famous hashtable-inspired persistent data structure inspired to us by the Clojure community (Clojure, being a language focused on concurrency and therefore wisely avoiding mutable state, has resulted in some fairly interesting work in the area of persistent data structures).

Comment: Do you know why some module is functional ,why some like Hashtbl is imperative?