# Set function for 2-dimensional array in OCaml

Tags: arrays, memory-management, multidimensional-array, ocaml

I am writing basic functions for 2 dimensional array. There are two ways to write "set" function. The first one consists in making a copy of the matrix and then modifying it:

```
let copy_matrix (m: 'a array array): 'a array array =
  let l = Array.length m in
    if l = 0 then m else
      let result = Array.make l m.(0) in
        for i = 0 to l - 1 do
           result.(i) <- Array.copy m.(i)
        done;
        result

let set_copy (m: 'a array array) (r: int) (c: int) (v: 'a): 'a array array =
  let m' = copy_matrix m in
  m'.(r).(c) <- v;
  m'
```

The second one just modifies directly on the matrix:

```
let set (m: 'a array array) (r: int) (c:int) (v: 'a) : unit =
  m.(r).(c) <- v
```

I think if it was in Java it would be obvious that the second function is quicker and more economic than the first one. However, someone (I forgot) told me that 1) the memory management of OCaml is so smart that `set_copy` does not cost very much, and 2) there are some reasons (I forgot) that it is better to use `set_copy` than `set`.

Could anyone tell me if this is true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need persistent arrays (you need to preserve all versions for backtracking purposes, etc.), the copying version is much better of course, but it will be slow. We discussed persistent arrays datastructures in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699794/what-is-the-most-efficient-implementation-of-arrays-with-functional-updates/14703968#14703968), you should consider using them instead of plain arrays if you want persistence. Handling matrix by using persistent arrays of persistent arrays will probably work rather well. Of course you can also use a [Map](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.html) with keys of type `(int * int)` as a starting point (but the access cost are non-neglectible).

If you don't need persistent (you never need to keep the "old" array around), avoiding copy and keeping the standard datatypes is better.

Also, you can implement `matrix_copy` as

```
let matrix_copy m = Array.map Array.copy m
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's any memory management magic that can cover for copying an entire array every time you want to change one value.

There are very good reasons to use immutable data, that apply to arrays as well as everything else. But unless the arrays are small, the copying code you show will impose a pretty serious cost.

There are other ways to represent arrays (e.g., as difference lists or trees) that don't require so much copying. But of course they have their own problems.